# Pandas - Copying row as new columns for every row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of 18207x65. Each row corresponds to a player, each column to an attribute.

I.e.

```
╔═════════════╦═══════╦═══════╦═════╦════════╗
║             ║ Attr1 ║ Attr2 ║ ... ║ Attr65 ║
╠═════════════╬═══════╬═══════╬═════╬════════╣
║ Player1     ║       ║       ║     ║        ║
║ Player2     ║       ║       ║     ║        ║
║ .           ║       ║       ║     ║        ║
║ .           ║       ║       ║     ║        ║
║ .           ║       ║       ║     ║        ║
║ Player18207 ║       ║       ║     ║        ║
╚═════════════╩═══════╩═══════╩═════╩════════╝
```

I want the user to type in a name, for the program to match that name with the corresponding row, and then calculate some measure of difference between that row and every other row (individually) for each attribute. Mean squared deviation or something similar seems reasonable.

My instinct is to select the desired row and then "copy & paste" this 1x30 item into each row such that there are 30 new columns, each of which has the same number repeated across 18207 rows.

I.e.

```
╔════════╦═════╦═════╦══════╦══════╦═════╦══════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════╦═════════╗
║        ║ At1 ║ ... ║ At35 ║ At36 ║ ... ║ At65 ║ CP_At35 ║ CP_At36 ║ ... ║ CP_At65 ║
╠════════╬═════╬═════╬══════╬══════╬═════╬══════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════╬═════════╣
║ P1     ║     ║     ║      ║      ║     ║      ║ a       ║ b       ║     ║ c       ║
║ .      ║     ║     ║      ║      ║     ║      ║ a       ║ b       ║     ║ c       ║
║ .      ║     ║     ║      ║      ║     ║      ║ a       ║ b       ║     ║ c       ║
║ .      ║     ║     ║      ║      ║     ║      ║ a       ║ b       ║     ║ c       ║
║ CP     ║     ║     ║ a    ║ b    ║     ║ c    ║ a       ║ b       ║     ║ c       ║
║ .      ║     ║     ║      ║      ║     ║      ║ a       ║ b       ║     ║ c       ║
║ .      ║     ║     ║      ║      ║     ║      ║ a       ║ b       ║     ║ c       ║
║ .      ║     ║     ║      ║      ║     ║      ║ a       ║ b       ║     ║ c       ║
║ P18207 ║     ║     ║      ║      ║     ║      ║ a       ║ b       ║     ║ c       ║
╚════════╩═════╩═════╩══════╩══════╩═════╩══════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════╩═════════╝
```

From there I would create 30 new columns again and do (stat_x - chosen_player_stat_x)^2 for each of those columns.

This seems a pretty unwieldy way to do this whole operation. I would appreciate any streamlined alternatives.

Assuming this is the best/a reasonable way to go about it, my specific problem is in "copying & pasting" the single row across to each row.

```
    chosen_player = input()
    chosen_player_index = df1[df1['Name'] == chosen_player].index[0]
    chosen_player_stats = df1.iloc[chosen_player_index:chosen_player_index+1, 35:]
```

(The attributes I want to compare run from column 35 onwards.)

I've selected the 1x30 block of data I want, but don't know whether I should be using join/append/concat/merge and/or a for loop to "copy & paste" it across.

Thank you kindly to anyone who offers any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd only select the row and create another dataframe for the ouput:

```
import pandas as pd

chosen_player = input()
chosen_player_row = d1.query("Name == @chosen_player").iloc[0] 
# you can also check that you have selected only one row with the filter

def your_diff(x, y):
    return (x-y)**2

result_df = pd.DataFrame({})
# or say result_df = df1.iloc[:, :35].copy() if you want some attributes, 
# and I guess you'd want at least Name

stats = list(df1.columns[35:]) # best would be to already have 
# your list of stats for which you want to make the computation

for stat in stats:
    result_df[stat] = df1[stat].apply(lambda x: your_diff(x, chosen_player_row[stat])
```

Comment: Hi Vincent,
Thanks a lot for your response.

I tried it exactly as above. 

Firstly it calls a syntax error at 
result_df = df1.iloc[, :35].copy()

I assume there should be something before the comma in [, :35]. Just an extra lone colon before the comma lets it run, I don't know if that's what you intended. 


Secondly, when I run:
print(result_df) at the end - outside of the for loop - it prints something identical to df1.

I don't know why that is, but if I run:
print(list(df1.columns[35:]))                      (in place of stats=)

it returns an empty set. 

Any idea?

Comment: Hey ; for point 1, you are right, sorry for the typo. For your second point, that would happen if you have less than 35 columns in `df1`. I thought your variables were running from column 35? But here best practice would be to already have your list of stats for which you want to make the computation

Comment: Thanks VIncent. It worked with some tinkering. The iloc for results_df needed to run from 35 to the end, not up to 35 as you had it.

Additionally, your query to select the player row gave the data as a series of 1-column rows, which wasn't useful, so I reverted to my original method of using index then pulling out the stats from that index.